# Оптимизация JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Уже наверное целый месяц делаю небольшую игру на HTML5 Canvas и стал разочарован результатом. Сама игра работает на 5 с плюсом, все работает и отображается как надо, а вот fps оставляет желать лучшего. Я понял что нужно это дело оптимизировать, стал читать статьи и всякое прочее с этим связанное, сделал оптимизацию, но ФПС проседать не перестал, при этом в самой игре нет каких-либо сложных вещей, самое сложное - это массив из 40 объектов, который рисуется на холсте, разве это так много для JavaScript? Как вообще узнать в каком месте утекает память? возможно я что-то где-то упустил.

Решил проверить какой fps будет на обычном пустом холсте, почему выдает такой низкий понять не могу. У меня держит около 40.

http://jsfiddle.net/1tkftzyg/4/

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если вы предоставите больше конкретики: приведете код или хотя бы часть кода, в котором вы предполагаете возможную утечку памяти. Очень трудно что-то советовать, не видя ситуацию целиком. Если же вы хотите найти проблему самостоятельно и ищете инструмент для поиска утечки памяти в браузере, тогда нужно немного переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: я ищу и то и другое, предположений у меня нет, но я могу просто показать код который выполняется каждый кадр, но для его анализа потребуется время, а у здешних людей его обычно нет

Comment: самый обычный canvas, без каких-либо библиотек, рэндер происходит в цикле, перебирая массив из 40 элементов, рисуются 40 ромбов в заданных координатах и все

Comment: @shatal я не говорю что в коде все хорошо, просто там нет ничего такого, т.е. обычные процедуры ожидания загрузки всех изображений, создание как раз этого самого массива, и создание игрового "лупа". Вот сижу профилирую, увеличивается Used JS Heap, пока не знаю что это такое, но уже пошел гуглить :) спасибо за советы

Comment: Решил проверить какой fps будет на обычном пустом холсте, почему выдает такой низкий понять не могу. У меня держит около 40.

http://jsfiddle.net/1tkftzyg/4/

Comment: @shatal сколько выдает у Вас? Тестирую в хроме

Comment: Если считаю по другому алгоритму, то вроде бы как 60 fps выдает, вот только все равно скачки бывают, хотя возможно из-за погрешности. http://jsfiddle.net/1tkftzyg/5/

Comment: Ясно, вообщем нужно по мимо вычисления дельты еще и сглаживать ее? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да! Дельта это не только время, но и значение расстояния на который перемещается объект. И если из-за падения fps дельта увеличивается, то её нужно сгладить, чтобы избежать увеличения расстояния.

Answer (score 2):

Первое что хочется посоветовать после просмотра Ваших ссылок, это научится пользоваться профилировщиком в браузере при помощи которого можно обнаружить утечки, узкие места, а так же он показывает fps. 
Лично я не люблю профилирующие инструменты в chrom, а использую, на мой взгляд самый лучший, IE. Так же нужно заметить что обязательно нужно и в firefox отдельно проверять, так как с canvas у него нелады и он урезает его возможности почти в два раза.

А теперь о Вашей проблеме. Скачки fps это вполне нормальная и обыденная история. Но Вас смущает дерганная анимация. Это недуг был всегда и лечится он лишь сглаживанием дельты времени. То есть Вам нужно в игре строить всю анимацию не на "тиках" таймера, а на прошедшем времени. Но и прошедшее время не помогает до той поры, пока его не начать сглаживать. 
Что это означает. Вот представьте, что Вы создаете анимацию движения квадратика с лева на права на расстояние 100px за одну секунду при установленном браузере обновлении 60fps в секунду.
Что Вы для этого делаете? Вы берете и делите расстояние 100px на 60sec, что равно 1.6. При хорошем fps вызов функции обновления рендера вызывется 60 раз в секунду и умножая прошедшее время на заранее установленное значение (1.6)
движение будет выглядеть плавным. Но если fps падает, то промежутки время увеличиваются и тем самым объекты начинают прыгать, так как при десяти обновлениях они удаляются на десять равных отрезков в 1,6 а при скачке fps это значение так же увеличивается. 
По этому выход один - создавать функцию сглаживания времени и строить всю анимацию на этом времени.

И если Вам не понятно что я пытался донести, поищите в гугле статьи, так как эта тема не одной большой статьи.

Comment: спасибо, я прекрасно Вас понял, да я пробовал умножать скорость всех объектов на дельту, но пришлось отказаться от этого метода т.к. в игре нужно действовать незамедлительно (игра на реакцию), то при большом рывке fps в ту или другую сторону происходит рывок и игры такой же резкий... хотя сейчас опять попробовать решил сгладить все дельтой, выглядит не очень то и гладко :(

Comment: Вы наверное гений! Написать функцию сглаживания времени ТАК БЫСТРО! 
И негладко быть не может, Вы же сглаживаете...

Comment: значит я Вас не понял

Comment: Значит в гугл! Статей миллионы, как искать я уже сказал.